# scanning the first 2 characters at once in a string

Tags: java

I need to scan an input of 2 chars at once and can't seem to figure it out. 
If I have `move = scan.next().charAt(0)` then all it will give me is the first character but I need to first 2 characters in the string

```
public void getChoice(){

    move = ' ';
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your next move: ");

    move = scan.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println(move);
}
```

Comment: Look up `substring()` method of `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the String in one variable by doing:

```
String str = scan.next();
```

And now get the first 2 chars.

```
char first = str.chatAt(0);
char second = str.chatAt(1);
```

Now you have the chars.

Any doubt, I'm here :)